# Распечатать pdf без открытия

Tags: javascript, pdf, print, setonclicklistener

Нашла тут http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Xc9/1/ вот такой код для кнопки печати:

```
function openWin(url){
        var myWindow=window.open(url,'PrintWindow','width=700,height=400');
        myWindow.focus();
        myWindow.print();
        myWindow.close();
    } 
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="openWin('/uploads/docs/596e1548cf35c.pdf')"/>
```

В урл я передаю путь к пдф файлу? который мне надо печатать. 
Если комментировать последнюю строчку функции myWindow.close(); - на печать выводится pdf все класс только окно не закрывается после печати, но с myWindow.close() - на печать идет пустая страница.

Как печатать pdf в 1 клик без остающихся левых окон?

Comment: Если сайты на моём принтере начнут в один клик по ссылке печатать рекламу - я сойду с ума.

Comment: ))не придирайтесь к словам. На 1 клик открывается окно печати для подтверждения с предпросмотром. Для самой печати нужен еще 1 клик!

Comment: может pdf ещё не успевает отрисоваться на странице и по этому ничего не печатается, попробуйте добавить timeout

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Попробовала - да если маленький таймаут то страница пуста, если больше успевает прогрузится. Но окно закрывается независимо от действий пользователя((Можно и не успеть нажать принт.